Passing an @objc enum to dictionary value will causes an allocate issue?
I'm facing an issue that occurs on iOS 14.6, when trying to pass an @objc enum  ConnectState to dictionary value, the app will crash with malloc error:
AppName(645,0x16f61f000) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=1152921504606863360, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
AppName(645,0x16f61f000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

@objc enum ConnectState: UInt8 {
    case connected = 0x00
    case disConnected = 0x01
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .connected:
            return "connected"
        case .disConnected:
            return "disConnected"
        }
    }
}

struct ConstValue {
      static let connectState = "connectState"
}

I set a malloc_error_break breakpoint, and it stopped at userInfo[ConstValue.connectState] = connectState.rawValue,
func connectStateChange(_ connectState: ConnectState, _ serialNumber: String) {
     var userInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
     //ConstValue.connectState is a string declared in ConstValue struct
     userInfo[ConstValue.connectState] = connectState.rawValue//breakPoint
     userInfo[ConstValue.serialNumber] = serialNumber
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(Global.HomeDeviceStateChange), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

I also tried to init a ConstValue enum by it's rawValue and pass it to userInfo's value, sadly didn't workout.
guard let connectStateItem = ConnectState(rawValue: connectState.rawValue) else {
      uniLogger.error(TAG, "\(#function) Error, Failed to init a ConnectState item from it's rawValue: \(connectState.rawValue)")
      return
}
userInfo[ConstValue.connectState] = connectStateItem
userInfo[ConstValue.serialNumber] = serialNumber

If I simply pass the parameter to notification's userInfo would work fine, but I need post both serialNumber and ConnectState, and why would this work?
func connectStateChange(_ connectState: ConnectState, _ serialNumber: String) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(Global.HomeDeviceStateChange), object: nil, userInfo: [ConstValue.connectState:connectState])
}


Cannot reproduce. Please show a [mcve].

In the notification you pass the enum not its rawValue. Why do you want to use the rawValue as you declared it as objc which enable it to be shared with Objective-C ?

@PtitXav Yes,  I was intended to pass enum to notification, the rawValues is for testing, since the allocate error.

Objective-C enums can't have functions or computed properties. This might be the reason behind the crash. The best option would be to pass the raw value through the userInfo and convert it to an enum value on the recipient side, which you have already done.
